# How to avoid repeating the same function to allow modifier keys on click on the link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the users have the option to do cmd+click on the name and role, so that the page related to it opens up in a new tab.

Following code is how I am handling it right now. I want a better solution of writing this code → instead of repeating the same function I want to handle both the scenario in one function.

```
redirectToUser = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { userId } = getUsersData(user);
    if (e.metaKey) {
      window.open(`/v2/users/${userId}/`, '_blank');
    } else {
      this.props.history.push(`/v2/users/${userId}/`);
    }
  };

  redirectToRole = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { roleId } = getUsersData(user);
    if (e.metaKey) {
      window.open(`/v2/roles/${roleId}/`, '_blank');
    } else {
      this.props.history.push(`/v2/roles/${roleId}/`);
    }
  };

  renderDataList = () => {
    const {  user } = this.props;
    const { name, roleType } = getUsersData(user);

    const dataList = [
      { label: 'Name', value: name, onClick: e => this.redirectToUser(e) },
      { label: 'Role', value: roleType, onClick: e => this.redirectToRole(e) }
    ];
    return dataList;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
redirectTo = url => e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (e.metaKey) {
      window.open(url);
   } else {
      this.props.history.push(url);
   }
};

renderDataList = () => {
  const {  user } = this.props;
  const { name, roleType, roleId, userId } = getUsersData(user);

  const dataList = [
     { label: 'Name', value: name, onClick: this.redirectTo(`/v2/users/${userId}`) },
     { label: 'Role', value: roleType, onClick: this.redirectTo(`/v2/roles/${roleId}`) }
  ];
  return dataList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be cleaned up more if you wanted, but it should work, I just abstracted the logic to a generic `redirect` function which builds the specific functions

```
redirect = (userKey, routeSlug) => {
  return e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user } = this.props;
    const attr = user[userKey];
    if (e.metaKey) {
      window.open(`${routeSlug}/${attr}`, "_blank")
    } else {
      this.props.history.push(`${routeSlug}/${attr}`);
    }
  }
}

redirectToUser = this.redirect("userId", `/v2/users`)
redirectToRole = this.redirect("roleId", `/v2/roles`)

renderDataList = () => {
    const {  user } = this.props;
    const { name, roleType } = getUsersData(user);

    const dataList = [
      { label: 'Name', value: name, onClick: e => this.redirectToUser(e) },
      { label: 'Role', value: roleType, onClick: e => this.redirectToRole(e) }
    ];
    return dataList;
  };
```

Comment: Had a few doubts @BillMetcalf 
1. Where is the ```userKey``` argument been used?
2. Whats the use of this line? ---> ```const atte = user[key];``` its not used anywhere else

Comment: woops good catch, I rushed too much with the response. I have updated it and now it should work